# Replace date from one dataframe to another if it's newer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

So I've hit a wall here and I feel it's pretty simple but can't get it to work.

I have two dataframes that I want to compare the dates and update one with the other's date if it's newer.

Here's the first dataframe (df1):

```
Unit Number    Date         Score
SAH-459        1/24/2019    0.951
SAH-450        2/3/2019     0.852
SAH-399        10/5/2019    0.354
```

And here's the second one (df2):

```
Unit Number    ActualDate
SAH-459        1/30/2019
SAH-450        2/3/2019
SAH-399        9/28/2019
```

So I would like only the date from SAH-459 to update to 1/30/2019 since it's newer

Here is what I've done so far:

```
unitlist = df1['Unit Number'].unique()    #gets array with unique Unit Numbers

for unit in unitlist:
    date1 = df1.loc[df1['Unit Number'] == unit, 'Date'].values
    date2 = df2.loc[df2['Unit number'] == unit, 'ActualDate].values

    if date2 > date1:
        df1.at[[unit],'Date'] = date2
```

However it's throwing this error:

```
"None of [Index(['SAH-459'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

I must say that the unique unit list of both dataframes are not the same. There might be some units missing from df1 into df2 and vice versa.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd like to point out that part of the reason why I'm struggling is because both dataframes don't have the same number of units or in the same order. (there are no repeats in either DF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1: same units in both dataframes**
Let's first create the 2 dataframes with:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Unit_Number": ["SAH-459", "SAH-450", "SAH-399"],
        "Date": ["1/24/2019", "2/3/2019", "10/5/2019"],
        "Score": [0.951, 0.852, 0.354],
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Unit_Number": ["SAH-459", "SAH-450", "SAH-399"],
        "ActualDate": ["1/30/2019", "2/3/2019", "9/28/2019"],
    }
)
```

In order to do the update you should set `Unit_Number` as the index and transform the dates columns to **datetime** with:

```py
# Set index
df1 = df1.set_index("Unit_Number")
df2 = df2.set_index("Unit_Number")

# Transform to date
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df2["ActualDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["ActualDate"])
```

So now you can create a filter of which units have a date in `df2` that is greater than the date in `df1` and use it to update the dates of those units in `df1` with:

```py
mfilter = df2["ActualDate"] > df1["Date"]
df1.loc[mfilter, "Date"] = df2.loc[mfilter, "ActualDate"]
```

> This will work if **both** dataframes have the same units and in the **same order**.

And if you need it you can reset the indexs after doing this update with:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

**Case 2: different units in both dataframes**

Let's add more units to test this case:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Unit_Number": ["SAH-459", "SAH-450", "SAH-399", "SAH-777"],
        "Date": ["1/24/2019", "2/3/2019", "10/5/2019", "4/29/2019"],
        "Score": [0.951, 0.852, 0.354, 0.982],
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Unit_Number": ["SAH-459", "SAH-450", "SAH-399", "SAH-999"],
        "ActualDate": ["1/30/2019", "2/3/2019", "9/28/2019", "1/12/2019"],
    }
)
```

You will need to do the same:

```py
df1 = df1.set_index("Unit_Number")
df2 = df2.set_index("Unit_Number")

# Transform to date
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df2["ActualDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["ActualDate"])
```

They key is to reindex `mfilter` using the index from `df1` and then reindex `mfilter` in `df2.loc`:

```py
mfilter = df2["ActualDate"].reindex(df1.index) > df1["Date"]
df1.loc[mfilter, "Date"] = df2.loc[mfilter.reindex(df2.index).fillna(False), "ActualDate"]
```

> This will **always** work

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

How would I be able to handle a situation where they're not necessarily in the same order and not the same number of units in each dataframe?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to power through a painful for loop and always forget to realize that Pandas has a fantastic toolbox under the hood to do everything in C in two lines of Python code.

Comment: Yes, it is always better if you can avoid for loops when using pandas, especially if you have some data to process

Comment: Hey sorry to keep bugging you but would this later approach take care of these cases:

-If "Unit Number" is in DF1 but not in DF2: Ignore it and keep the DF1 date

-If "Unit Number" is not in DF1 but it is in DF2: Add it to DF1 with the date of DF2

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what it does. This is the reason behind all those reindexs

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks a lot. Pandas is definitely quite the tool